# VB.net Class Structuring

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to make a class where I feed it a string to expose the properties and methods, similar to this:

```
Dim PayCheck as Double = 0
With Employee("Bob")
    .Age =  30
    .Position = Engineer
    .Department = Operations
    .Company = SPP
    .Wage = 30
    .HoursWorked = 45
    PayCheck = .CalculatePayCheck
End With
```

Comment: you mean you want a class with exposed methods?

Comment: It's called a getter and setter

Comment: Some odds you are confusing a Dictionary with Reflection.  "Feeding a string" is too unclear, I'd guess that you want Type.GetProperty().

Comment: I am storing it in a dictionary, because once I've collected all the data and set the class properties, I will have to iterate through them to run methods. So I thought I needed a container to iterate them. And I apologize if I I don't know the proper ways to ask, I only learned classes a week ago!

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap a Dictionary(Of Employee) into a class and have a `CurrentEmployee` property which is set from the dictionary when you feed it the string.

Then all properties could be retrieved with respect to the `CurrentEmployee`. But you'd have to replicate every property from the employee type and wrap the appropriate property from `CurrentEmployee`, or maybe use reflection to fetch the correct property by name from `CurrentEmployee`.

Does that help?

Comment: yu_ominae, I may have not elaborated enough on what I am wanting to do. I am storing classes in a dictionary where the key is the employee name, and the value is the class. This is working just fine, but I feel like I should use a class of classes instead, where my master employee class holds the individual employee classes. I would then be able to directly access the employee class by feeding the master class the employee's name (hopefully my question shows this).

Comment: I'm sorry to waste everybody's time. I played around with my code and answered my own question.

Comment: Cool, glad you figured it out. Could you post the solution for future reference?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should use a class of classes,
Which termed a collection 
so you have something along the lines of...

```
Class Employee
  Property Id (a unique numeric identifier)
  Property Name
  Property Age
  Property Position
  Property Department
  Property Company
  Property Wage
  Property HoursWorked
  Property PayCheck
  Method  CalculatePayCheck()
End Class
```

And then your collection of Employees

```
Class Employees
  Property AllEmployees as generic.list(of Employee)
  Property ThisEmployee(Id as Long) as Employee
  Property ThisEmployee(Name as string) as Employee
  Method AddEmployee(Name, Age, Position, Department, Company, Wage, HoursWorked, PayCheck)
  Method  RemoveEmployee(Name)
End Class
```

the idea of the Id field is that names may be duplicated,
like for example two "Steven Smith"s  may be employed

And to access the employee you can do as you did

```
With ThisEmployee("Bob")
```

or

```
With ThisEmployee(6)
```

where it will extract the seventh employee as most collections are zero based (start at zero)

## Update

With ref to the sample code above....
Yes JoeB, Because it is a generic collection you may use a 
for/next loop 
or a for/each loop
or do/while loop

something like...

```
For Counter = 0 to Employees.Count -1
  'print name using the EMPLOYEES collection object
  Print AllEmployees(Counter).Name
  'print name using the EMPLOYEE object (single employee using the Id property)
  Print ThisEmployee(Counter).Name
Next
```

In some cases you may need to INSTANCE the object before using it...
like so...

```
Dim TmpEmployee as Employee
For Counter = 0 to Employees.Count -1
  'get employee from collection
  TmpEmployee = AllEmployees(Counter)
  'print name using the EMPLOYEE object 
  Print TmpEmployee.Name
  TmpEmployee = nothing
Next
```

Comment: Zaf, this looks great. I just have one more question. Could I iterate over the employees? something like this? For each Obj as Object in Employees.AllEmployees?